# MYSQLi inserting new row into database

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a mysqli database table that is set up like so

id---email---password.

What I want to do is insert a new row of information here. This is what I've tried:

EDIT: This is how I'm connecting to the database, saving the connection in a global variable:

```
global $db;
$db = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database' );
if ( $db->connect_errno > 0 ) {
die( 'Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']' );
```

}

```
function juice_sign_up( $email, $password, $password_confirm )
{
    global $db;
    $emailCheck = 'SELECT email FROM user WHERE email = $email';
    if($emailCheck == 'NULL'){
        $hashPass = password_hash($password);
        INSERT INTO user VALUES ($email, $hashPassword);
}
```

This is where that function is getting the variables:

```
    if( isset($_POST('password_confirm'))){
      juice_sign_up($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['password_confirm']);
    }
```

I'm very new to using MYSQL and don't fully understand the syntax yet. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Sidenote: Use 1x equal, not 2x `WHERE email == $email'` - do `WHERE email = $email'` However, `$email` should be wrapped in quotes since it's not an integer. This is SQL, not PHP.

Comment: Putting raw SQL in PHP can't be helping! `INSERT INTO user VALUES ($email, $hashPassword);`

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call (you can use "null !== func()" instead) in this is the error im getting.

Comment: Have you tried `$emailCheck = "SELECT email FROM user WHERE email = '$email'";` instead? @Corjava However this line `INSERT INTO user VALUES ($email, $hashPassword);` am questioning.

Comment: I haven't no, but I did just change it to WHERE email LIKE $email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things are wrong here. You don't execute the select query (you just build the string). And the insert statement is added as if it is PHP code, but that's not how you execute statements. Also, you need to at least escape input to your insert statement, or rather even use *parameter binding*.

To execute the queries, you can use [mysqli->query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). It returns a query result object (for select queries), or `true` (for DML statements). It returns `false` in case of an error.

I address the issues in the comments in the following snippet:

```
function juice_sign_up( $email, $password, $password_confirm )
{
    global $db;
    // The line below just assigns a string to $emailCheck. You still need to execute the query.
    $emailCheck = 'SELECT email FROM user WHERE email == $email';

    // Try to execute it.
    $queryResult = $db->query($emailCheck);
 
    // Check if the query succeeded and if a row is found.
    // For select queries an object is returned from which you can fetch the results.
    if ($queryResult !== false && $queryResult->fetch_object() === false)
    {
        $hashPass = password_hash($password);
        // Inserting should be done in a similar way. Build a query, and execute it.
        $email = $db->real_escape_string($email);
        $hashPassword = $db->real_escape_string($hashPassword);
        // Mind the escaping of illegal characters (above) and the quotes (below).
        $statement = "INSERT INTO user VALUES ('$email', '$hashPassword')";

        // Note: you won't get a result object for insert statements.
        $result = $db->query($statement);
        // Check the value of result to see if it worked.
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I write $hashPass = password_hash($password); but then later you say $hashPassword, is this a mistake?

Comment: anyway, thank you for the help, this is very informative and helped me understand MYSQLi more.

Comment: $hashPass vs $hashPassword is a mistake. I based the code on the snippet you posted in the question, but there there are also two different variables. I didn't notice that. It should indeed be the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute a SQL query like that.

try this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO user VALUES ($email, $hashPassword);';
$db_con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
$result = $db_con->query($sql);
```

You have to "fetch" the result to get the data you want, read the documentation how to use it. :)

Comment: with oop its not necessary to connect to the database since its already in the constructor of mysqli

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function juice_sign_up( $email, $password, $password_confirm )
{
   global $db;
   $emailCheck = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT email FROM user WHERE email = $email');
   if($emailCheck == 'NULL'){
       $hashPass = password_hash($password);
       mysqli_query($db, INSERT INTO user VALUES ($email, $hashPassword));
```

}